# How do I bind an Ienumerable<TModel> in a foreach loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC2 view which is strongly bound to a model.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AdjustmentModel>>" %>
```

And in the View I have.

```
         foreach (var adjustment in Model)
           {%>
         <tr row="<%: row %>">
            <td class="nonSelectable" column="0">
                <div>
                    ...I want to put a textbox here that has name="someId" 
                   and val="someVal" but how?
                </div>
            </td>

            }%>
```

The model is

```
class AdjustmentModel
{
    public int ID;
    public int amount;
}
```

I just can't figure the delegate that I pass to Html.TextBoxFor() because when I pass a model the intellisense won't work as I'm passing in an Ienumerable so how do I use the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you using editor templates. This way you don't need to write any loops and still keep the strong typing:

```
<table>
    <%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
</table>
```

and then you define an editor template which will be automatically rendered for each element of your collection (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AdjustmentModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AdjustmentModel>" 
%>
<tr>
    <td class="nonSelectable" column="0">
        <div>
            <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID) %>
            <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.amount) %>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is important to respect the convention which is to locate your editor template inside the `~/Views/CurrentController/EditorTemplates` or `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder. The name of the template must be the type used in the collection. So for example if you have `IEnumerable<AdjustmentModel>`, the file must be called `AdjustmentModel.ascx` and obviously strongly typed to `AdjustmentModel`. This template will then be automatically called for each element.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Html.TextBox**

```
<%= Html.TextBox("SomeId", "SomeVal") %>
```